# Angular2 Duplicated model VS One model with nullable fields?

Tags: rest, angular, django-rest-framework, models

Consider a models classe Article in an angular2 application. This classs is used by 4 components to show, edit and create data. It's used by a service to interact with REST API. for each use case I need to work with a specefic set of fields. (eg. components A uses title, body, and author, (components B uses all fields). Is it better to create a customized class for each component/service that contains only used fields ? Another option is to use one class that contains all fields and ignore not used fields for a specific use case ?

Comment: I don't think anybody can help you with that. That depends entirely on your requirements. If you ask for opinions, then SO is not the right place. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions

Comment: It's a common issue most of angular2 projects are facing I guess. I am asking experimented Angular2 users for which criteria decides for which option to go with to not regret after 6 months of work